# How to create a clickable animated dropdown in CSS Flexbox without Jquery?

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox, css-animations, css-transitions

[image: Main Page]

I have several one-after-another anchor tags as you can see when I click one of them a div appears below it like that:

[image: Second One]

HTML, CSS AND JS Codes:

**HTML**

I just got the first anchor tag the other ones go the same.

```
       <div class="category2">
         <a href="#" class="items2" id="itemOne">
             Elektrikli El Aletleri  
         </a>
         <div class="subCategory" id="subListOne">
            <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a>
            <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a>
            <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a>
            <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a>
            <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a>
            <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a>
            <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a>
            <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a>
            <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a>
            <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a>
            <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a>
            <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a>
            <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a>
            <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a>
            <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a>
            <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a>
            <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a>
        </div>

       ...
     </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.category2 {
    
    flex-direction: column;
    display:none;
    
   }
```

```
@media screen and (max-width:1220px) {
    
    .category2 {
        display: flex;
    }

    .category2 > a {
        height: 50px;
    }
}
```

```
.items2 {
    border:1px solid white; 
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 20px;
    font-size:20px;
    
}
```

```
 .subCategory {
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: darkslategrey;
    display: none;
    
 }
```

This ".active" class is added next to the ".subCategory" by clicking the anchor tag whose ID is "itemOne". So the div becomes seeable.

```
.active {
    display:flex
}
```

**JS**

```
    let itemOne = document.getElementById('itemOne');
    let subListOne = document.getElementById('subListOne');

    

    itemOne.addEventListener('click', () => {
         subListOne.classList.toggle('active');
     })
```

What I want to do is animate this event. I wanted to make the div slide down in some milliseconds. By the way, While I'm doing this I wanted to protect this div's display as a flex.

First I tried to do this with height property so instead of

```
.subCategory {
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: darkslategrey;
    display: none;

 }
```

I did that:

```
.subCategory {
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: darkslategrey;
    display: flex;
    height:0px;
    transition: all 0.7s ease

 }
```

and ".active" is:

```
.active {
    height:"auto";
}
```

But it didn't work out.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You use the max-height property instead of height. Set the overflow of subCategory to hidden. Then set its initial max-height to 0.

Then upon hover or focus, you make the max-height a large and impossible number like 9999px for example.

```
 <div class="category2" tabindex="1">
         <a href="#" class="items2" id="itemOne">
             Elektrikli El Aletleri  
         </a>
         <div class="subCategory" id="subListOne"> 
            <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a>
            <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a>
            <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a>
            <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a>
            <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a>
            <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a>
            <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a>
            <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a>
            <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a>
            <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a>
            <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a>
            <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a>
            <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a>
            <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a>
            <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a>
            <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a>
            <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a>
        </div>

     </div>

.category2 {
    
    flex-direction: column;
    display: flex;    
  }




@media screen and (max-width:1220px) {
    
    .category2 {
        display: flex;
    }

    .category2 > a {
        height: 50px;
    }
}

.items2 {
    border:1px solid white; 
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 20px;
    font-size:20px;
    
}
 .subCategory {
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: darkslategrey; 
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
 }

.category2:hover .subCategory{
    max-height: 999px;
}
```

Take a look at what I've done [here](https://codepen.io/danieloseni/pen/QWxoMEM)

Answer (score 0):

You can animate the `max-height` property

```js
let itemOne = document.getElementById('itemOne');
let subListOne = document.getElementById('subListOne');

itemOne.addEventListener('click', () => {
  subListOne.classList.toggle('active');
})
```

```css
.category2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.category2>a {
  height: 50px;
}

.items2 {
  border: 1px solid white;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.subCategory {
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: darkslategrey;
  display: flex;
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.7s ease
}

.subCategory > a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.active {
  max-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="category2">
  <a href="#" class="items2" id="itemOne">Elektrikli El Aletleri</a>
  <div class="subCategory" id="subListOne">
    <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a>
    <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a>
    <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a>
    <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a>
    <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a>
    <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a>
    <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a>
    <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a>
    <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a>
    <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a>
    <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a>
    <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a>
    <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a>
    <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a>
    <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a>
    <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a>
    <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But with the first click, the animation is not happening like the second one. The first one opens directly. @Gerard

Comment: @AlimGölcük Aplologies. I've adjusted `max-height` for class `active`.  It was 9999 pixels which affected the animation.

Comment: Is there a way to solve this problem? @Gerard

Comment: @AlimGölcük Run the code now. I believe it works as it should after the change.

Comment: Yea I have tried that after your first comment. But I guess We can't handle that in a Dynamic way. Because as the larger the content of the div gets the heights might not be enough and we must change it always manually. @Gerard

Comment: Okay, I solve that problem without changing 9999px. We should just add  "transition: max-height 0.5s cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0, 1)" to the "subCategory" and that "transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out" to the "active" class. @Gerard